# mysql is not enabled in phpinfo() of php 5.3.1

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am having apache 2.2.14, php 5.3.1 and mysql 5.1.43 installed on vista. I am trying since 2 days to configure php to have mysql enable on phpinfo().

1. I modified php.ini to have extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"
2. modified the extension as extension="php_mysql.dll"
3. added "c:\php" to the "PATH" environment variable and restarted the vista.

after trying many combinations of putting php.ini, php_mysql.dll and libmysql.dll  in c drive and/or c:/windows and/or c:/windows/system32 now I am with no options!!

I do restart the apache after each modification. I used libmysql.dll present in mysql installation and that of older php version as php 5.3.1 has no libmysql.dll...

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit php.ini and add/uncomment a line to import the `php_mysql.dll` extention. Search for `;extention=php_mysql.dll` and remove the `;`. If you find this line without the `;` in front of it, you have another problem. If you don't find this line, add it without the `;`.

You can also try to put a `\` after the extention path: `extension_dir="c:\php\ext\"`

Comment: Hi dodo... , thanx for your time. I had done both changes what u suggested but still no effect on phpinfo(). can u advice me the correct places to put php.ini and libmysql.dll files if they are other that c:/php and c:/windows/system32 respectively. I dont see any other concern to deal with

Answer (score 0):

put php_mysql.dll in the "c:\php\ext" directory (and keep the `extension="php_mysql.dll"` uncommented [without the leading `;`])

Comment: hi Dan, thanx for the suggestion but I am with the mentioed changes. any other changes which should be there?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've edited the right php.ini. In case of doubt

```
<?php echo 'ini= "', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path'), '"';
```

will tell you which one is used by your php installation.

Maybe php tried to load the php-mysql extension and failed because of additional dependencies. That would cause a startup error entry in the [error.log](http://docs.php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.error-log).

Which php-build do you use? The php-mysql extension can either use libmysql.dll as transport layer or the new [mysqlnd (MySQL native driver)](http://docs.php.net/mysqlnd) module. You've added c:\php to PATH. That's usually done in order to let windows find libmysql.dll (though it's not necessary, there are other methods which I prefer). If php-mysql depends on libmysql.dll and windows can't find it loading php_mysql.dll will fail.
But if you're using the php.net build of php 5.3.1 the mysql module uses mysqlnd:

> Installation on Windows

In the official PHP distributions from 5.3 onwards, MySQL Native Driver is enabled by defaultThis module is built-in in the php.net build. You can test that by calling `php -m` in a  command shell. It prints all built-in modules.

Comment: hi VolkerK, thanx for your valuable opinion. I am getting nothng (blank page)on running the code <?php echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path'); 

which kind of additional dependency r u takhing about? Yes, I am using php 5.3.1 from php.net and I do have mysqlnd module present on phpinfo(). 
I am posting this question because I am getting the Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() after executing the code related to mysql_connect() on my php build 5.3.1.
looking for your suggestions and thanx for your time

Comment: Please try the "enhanced" info script (added ini="..." to the output to make sure "something" is always printed, a blank page could also mean "parse error", therefore it's better to always print "something"). If it still prints an empty value for cfg_file_path then this php instance didn't use/find any php.ini at all. see http://docs.php.net/configuration.file   (The additional dependency would have been libmysql.dll but since you're using mysqlnd this doesn't apply)

Comment: THANX VolkerK for showing me correct way to fix the issue :)
after executing the code correctly, I saw the empty path as ini="" . The issue was in the filename! I corrected my 'php.ini' file with correct file name(initially it was php.ini.ini) ;)  Now my phpinfo() is showing mysql too. (Now no more Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() ) Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to the user who said that we have to move the file `php.ini` to the folder `/bin` of the Apache server. it resolves me the same problem after more than one week of trying failed methods.

Of course we must uncomment in the file the two lines;

```
;extension=php_mysql.dll
;extensin_dir="ext"
```

by removing the semi-colon (`;`) and by specifying the full path for the extension library `php_mysql.dll` rather than `ext` as follows

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extensin_dir="c:\Apache22\php53\ext"
```

For me I installed Apache in the folder `c:\Apache22` and PHP in the folder `c:\Apache22\php53`, you must use your own values.

**NOTE**: Because `mysql_` functions like `mysql_connect()` become deprecated in PHP 5.5 and above, it is recommended to enable also the library `php_mysqli.dll` to use functions like `mysqli_` (improved version of `mysql_` functions). To do that it is simple, you just have to uncomment the line:

```
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

in the file PHP.ini as follows:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Answer (score -2):

Update April 7, 2013. Installed Windows 8 on an i7 Quad, HT 8, 3.62GHz, 12GBRAM.. Installed the latest version of MySQL, got it functioning properly. Installed the latest version of Apache Web Server, got it functioning properly. Installed the latest version of PHP, got it functioning properly. MySQL could not connect to the database. The error message was "mysql_connect function undefined". I copied the modified php.ini file into the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin", and restarted Apache web server...  then it all magically started working.!!! I hope this helps somebody with setting up their own Windows MySQL / PHP web server.