# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I know there is a ton of other questions like this, but none that I found answered my problem.

I get the following error `Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` with the following code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "MyUsername";
$password = "MyPassword";
$dbname = "MyDatabase";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
var_dump($conn);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(email) FROM subscribers WHERE email LIKE ?");
var_dump($stmt);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

var_dump($conn) returns:

```
object(mysqli)#2 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> NULL ["client_info"]=> NULL ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(2002) ["connect_error"]=> string(25) "No such file or directory" ["errno"]=> NULL ["error"]=> NULL ["error_list"]=> NULL ["field_count"]=> NULL ["host_info"]=> NULL ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> NULL ["server_info"]=> NULL ["server_version"]=> NULL ["stat"]=> NULL ["sqlstate"]=> NULL ["protocol_version"]=> NULL ["thread_id"]=> NULL ["warning_count"]=> NULL }
```

and var_dump($stmt) returns:

`NULL`

My query is correct, I tried it out in phpMyAdmin, it works.

The odd thing is that this exact code worked on my localhost, after uploading it it stopped working.

**EDIT**

After replacing `$stmt->execute();` with

```
if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}
```

And adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` I get the following errors:

`Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in [...]`

`Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in [...]`

`Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in [...]`

**EDIT 2**

[image: Mysqli settings]

Here are my mysqli settings are these the way they are meant to be?

Comment: You should firstly select email, and then take the rowCount function from PDO, there is some odd bugg with executing these queries in PDO...

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` here?  Why not `WHERE email = ?`? You should also log out your errors. `$conn->error` when the prepare fails.

Comment: @Jordy Not sure what you mean, I'm not using PDO but mysqli

Comment: @MikeBrant Just tried `WHERE email = ?` same result :(

Comment: @Lupy you could try the same thing as for mysqli. $conn->num_rows;

Comment: @Jordy He can't use num_rows if he can't get the query to execute.  And he currently can't get the query to execute, because he is not able to prepare it.

Comment: What does `var_dump($conn->error)` show if executed right after your failed prepare? You should always build code to handle failure and log errors and such.  Currently your code just assumes everything works fine.

Comment: @MikeBrant It shows NULL the same as `var_dump($stmt)`

Comment: Replace `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Weird that you are getting `NULL` as you should be either getting the `mysqli_stmt` object or `false` if there was a failure.  Are you showing all lines of code?

Comment: @MikeBrant are you asking if I pasted all lines of code in my question? If so no, above the code that I pasted I got all data from my html form, required a file set some variables and at the very end I have a redirect using `header();`

Comment: @Lupy I was wondering if there were intermittent lines that were omitted.  Seeing your update though it seems clear the problem might be that mysqli extension is not enabled on your server. If you would have checked for `$conn->connect_error` in your code, you would have caught this.  As it is, I missed this in that I didn't look at your var_dump for the mysqli object closely enough.  You can see the error noted there in your dump.

Comment: Plus, do up a seperate file with `<?php phpinfo();` that will show what's installed on the server.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Done, what am I looking for? API Extensions?

Comment: Lupy: That and anything related to `mysql` - `mysqli` - `pdo`. See these also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6285141/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2198154/ - @MikeBrant any other suggestions for the OP?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not sure what I need, do you mind having a look at my updated question? I posted the settings there...

Comment: I can't come up with anything. See if you can contact your hosting company. They'd be the ones to speak with in order to get tech support about this; which at this point looks like is what you need. In the meantime, try another type of query without prepared statements to see if you get results.

Comment: @RyanVincent I this particular scenario I did not even have an email address in my database, all the query does is check for how many rows there are with that particular email address. 0 is a valid result. The problem ended up being with the connection, I used "localhost" as a servername on a shared hosting server, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I contacted the hosting company and the solution was quite simple really. While connecting to the database I used "localhost" as a servername which does not work when you are on a shared hosting service. All I needed to do is to change it to the servername specified in my MySQL configuration.